What does "word/logon" mean in "I have given them your word" John 17:14?
John 17:14 ESV

"I have given them your word, and the world has hated them because they are not of the world, just as I am not of the world." My emphasis. [word/logon]

Here logon is singular and in John 1:1 logos is also singular. Is Jesus this "word"?
John 17:8 ESV

"For I have given them the words that you gave me, and they have received them and have come to know in truth that I came from you; and they have believed that you sent me."
[words/rhemata]

How does rhemata [plural John 17:8] contrast with logon [singular John 17:14]?
Is there an effect of this going from rhemata to logon?

Both works in v8 and v14 are direct objects.  Thus, they are accusative.
λόγον is the accusative singular of λόγος.  ῥήματα is the accusative plural of ῥῆμα.
There is some overlap in these two words.  Here are the senses of how they are used in the New Testament:
Figure 1. The Senses of λόγος in the New Testament (generated with Logos Bible Software.)

Figure 2. The Senses of ῥῆμα in the New Testament (generated with Logos Bible Software.)

Perhaps ῥήματα is plural because it seems to emphasize the physical or acoustical aspect a little more while λόγον tends to emphasize the meaning of the message.
A. T. Robertson comment:

The words (τα ρηματα [ta rēmata]). Plural, each word of God, as in 3:34, and of Christ (5:47; 6:63, 68), while the singular (τον λογον σου [ton logon sou]) in verses 6 and 14 views God’s message as a whole.
--
Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (Jn 17:8). Broadman Press.


+1. I was in the middle of writing a similar answer and yours appeared.  It is a good answer.
